# Save multiple PDFs from Excel to SharePoint and replace existing documents

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Every morning my team fills out interest rates into an Excel tab called "Interest Input".

1. Within this Excel file, there are 3 Tabs:
   "Output 1", "Output 2" and "Output 3".
   These outputs are generated by linking to the "Interest Input Tab".
2. For every output tab, we have to create a PDF:
   "Output 1.pdf", "Output 2.pdf" and "Output 3.pdf".
3. We then access a SharePoint, where we see the 3 output flies created the day before and replace them.
   "Output 1.pdf" from yesterday is replaced by "Output 1.pdf" from today. and so on.

An intranet page links to the three different Output files, so that anyone who accesses it will see the most recent PDF each day, when clicking on the link. (The intranet links are static and are not changed.)

How can I create a button, that triggers a macro, that will do the steps?

Answer (score 1):

**you shouldn't come here expecting someone to program it, here you should ask questions if you get stuck on specific things during development**

Open the Excel workbook in which you want to create the macro.
Press Alt + F11 to open the VBA editor.
In the VBA editor, go to "Insert" > "Module" to create a new module.
In the new module, paste the following code:

```
Sub SaveAndExportPDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Output 1" Or ws.Name = "Output 2" Or ws.Name = "Output 3" Then
            ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Save the macro by pressing "Ctrl + S".
Return to the Excel workbook.
Right-click on a blank area of the ribbon, select "Customize the Ribbon", and in the right-hand list, check the "Developer" checkbox.
In the "Developer" tab, click on "Insert" and select "Button (Form Control)".
Draw the button on the worksheet where you want it to appear.
Right-click the button and select "Assign Macro".
Select the macro you just created and click "OK".
Now, when you click the button, the macro will run and export the PDFs for the "Output 1", "Output 2", and "Output 3" worksheets.